# Does BizTalk server 2016 support Rosetta net accelerator?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

The link [BizTalk RosettaNet accelerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff720226.aspx) talks about its support in BizTalk server 2013. Does BizTalk server 2016 support Rosetta net accelerator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YES.**  The RosettaNet Accelerator ships with BizTalk Server 2016 and is fully supported.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any official documentation that in an explicit mode says BizTalk 2016 support Rosettanet, but in [What's New in BizTalk Server 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt670742.aspx) there some improvements related to Rosettanet:

> Supports the following Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) exchange system for signature keys in AS2, RosettaNet, and the MIME/SMIME encoder

or

> Supports the following SHA2-based digest methods in RosettaNet

Comment: Thanks, @felixmondelo Yeah, the setup package for BizTalk server 2016 contains an accelerator for RN 2013 so I guess it is compatible with Biztalk server 2016 as well.